# How to set path for python

Tags: python

I have installed pyton 2.7.3 in my localmachine (windows 7 ) and as instructed in http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html and I tried to set path using cmd prompt.

> set path=%path%;C:\python27

But when I typed **python**  in command line this error is showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File"<stdin>",line 1, in <module>
Nameerror:name 'python' is not defined
```

I also tried to add path manually

```
Start Menu > Control Panel > System & Security > System > Advanced System Settings/ 

Under System variables-path->edit and added this code  ;C:\python27
```

But still when I type **python** in command line I get the same error

What should I do?

Comment: It sounds like you're typing "python" inside Python, not at the system command line.  Describe how you are getting to the command line where you type this.

Comment: @BrenBarn  i am new to python ; i typed the code in python command line

Comment: If you're already at the Python command line, it's too late to set the path: you already are running Python.  As the documentation you linked to says, you need to type the "set path" stuff *in a DOS box* (i.e., by choosing "command prompt" from the start menu)

Comment: you can set sys.path in python ... but i dont think that will help him with whatever his problem actually is...

Comment: I recommend using Wing IDE or PyCharm to learn python, and not just the python command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be doing the second part, executing `python` command in python interpreter itself.

[image]